# JQuery Conflict and not sure how to fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, conflict

I know very little about javascript or what's causing the conflict. I have a jQuery calendar that is not showing up now that I've added the Lazy Loading jquery. I am not sure where to start with the noConflict script.

I have a home page where I using two jQuery files and I am getting a conflict. The first call is this:

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js
```

and the second is jQuery for Lazy Loading of a Bootstrap Carousel that I found online:

```
/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js
```

Comment: What does your actual includes look like in the html page? What is the actual error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has `noConflict` method for this cases. You can reed more about it at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Example usage of two version of jQuery in the same HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.noConflict demo</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="log">
  <h3>Before $.noConflict(true)</h3>
</div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>

<script>
var $log = $( "#log" );

$log.append( "2nd loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery + "<br>" );

// Restore globally scoped jQuery variables to the first version loaded
// (the newer version)

jq162 = jQuery.noConflict( true );

$log.append( "<h3>After $.noConflict(true)</h3>" );
$log.append( "1st loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery + "<br>" );
$log.append( "2nd loaded jQuery version (jq162): " + jq162.fn.jquery + "<br>" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```